# JSP file inherits duplicate variable from 2 different JSPs

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jboss

Comsider this simplification of a real problem with 3 old .jsp's:

I have **father.jsp** with declares variable '*sharedVar*'. Because internally it uses it.

Also **mother.jsp** declares that same variable '*sharedVar*'. Because internally it uses it.

Then, **son.jsp** imports both **father.jsp** and **mother.jsp**. Because it need to use the variable '*sharedVar*'.

The Eclipse rejects it with the error "**Duplicate local variable**"

Does somebody knows how to solve it?

Comment: If `sharedVar` is everywhere the same, `father.jsp` and `mother.jsp` should not declare it by their own, but import it from the same, e.g. import it from `ancestor.jsp`.

Comment: Either this ^ or import only `mother.jsp` *or* `father.jsp`

Answer (score 0):

If by "import" you mean `@include`, there's not really a solution for this other than defining a [prelude](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/javaserver-pages-3rd/0596005636/re180.html) file in the `web.xml` file that declares the `sharedVar` so that you only have it present one time regardless of whether you include either parent or *are* either parent.

Comment: Thank you. Finallly I solved it renaming the shared variables and reorganizing it all